# Making a table made with the react-virtualized Grid privative accessible to screen readers

Tags: accessibility, react-virtualized

I'm attempting to remediate a grid table made with react-virtualize for Accessibility. The client chose to render the table using only the Grid primitive instead of the Table primitive. Currently, the resulting table is completely inaccessible to screen reader users.

Has anyone been able to make such a table accessible? And How?

I tried adding in many of the roles and associations manually, but without a wrapping div for each row to mark role="row", I can't get anything to work.

Is there a way to render the Grid rows wrapped, so I can add the role="row"?